# Android Studio nagging for SDK in the wrong location

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

When trying to run Clean I get the following error:

> 09:42:05: Executing external tasks '**clean --debug --stacktrace**'...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > **The SDK directory 'C:\iSMP\ismp-starter-kit 1.6\PayEx_Android_Sample_App\android-studio-app\UsersblsAppDataLocalAndroidandroid-sdk' does not exist**.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1.302 secs The SDK directory 'C:\iSMP\ismp-starter-kit
>   1.6\PayEx_Android_Sample_App\android-studio-app\UsersblsAppDataLocalAndroidandroid-sdk' does not exist. 09:42:06: External tasks execution finished 'clean
>   --debug --stacktrace'.

I don't understand why it insists on looking for the SDK within project root (C:\iSMP\ismp-starter-kit 1.6\PayEx_Android_Sample_App\android-studio-app). I haven't specified that location anywhere, and that's not where the SDK is located.

I tried specifying the SDK location within local.properties, but that only changed the subfolder within project root:

> sdk.dir=\Users\bls\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

**Why does it keep looking in the wrong place, and how do I make it look outside of project root folder?**